# Do Google Classroom Calendars use Google Calendars API?

Tags: google-classroom

We are looking to integrate with Google Classroom in the near future, and one of the main questions is if the Google Classroom Calendars are able to be pulled using the Google Calendar API. I would assume the Calendar List endpoint would include the Classroom Calendar as an available calendar to sync with, but wanted to get some input from those who are using Google Classroom. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can fetch the calendar events from Google Classroom as long as the calendar events were created inside Google Classroom which is mentioned [here](https://support.google.com/edu/classroom/answer/6149237?hl=en).

Demo:

1. Go to a class.
2. Go to ABOUT section and click 'Open in Google Calendar'.
   [image]
3. Now it will open Google Calendar. Create a sample Event.
4. Go to [Calendar.list Try-It](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/list#try-it) and on the "Fields" textbox (above Execute button), check all the parameters. Execute. You will see all the events in your Google Calendar including ones those that belong to Google Classroom.
   [image]